# Router function - 'beforeEnter' takes default values from vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router, vuejs3

## What is the exact problem?

I'm building authentication app with vue.js. When I was dealing with secure routes I encountered the problem that the function 'beforeEnter' takes default values from vuex. It's problematic because of it makes me unable to create secure routes. I would be glad for your help!

### Here is route file

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import store from '../store/index'
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/globalData',
    name: 'GlobalData',
    component: () => import('../views/GlobalData.vue'),
    beforeEnter: (_, __, next) => {
      if (!store.state.isLoggedIn) {
        next('/about')
      }else {
        next()
      }
    }
  },
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})


export default router
```

### Here is my store

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

// Create a new store instance.
const store = createStore({
    state () {
        return {
            isLoggedIn: false,
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        setIsLoggedIn(state, bool) {
            state.isLoggedIn = bool;
        }
    }
})

export default store;
```

### Here is how isLoggedIn changes

```
import{ onBeforeMount, ref } from 'vue'
import fire from '@/firebase';
import { useStore } from 'vuex'


export default {
  setup() {

    const store = useStore()

    onBeforeMount(() => {
      fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
          store.commit('setIsLoggedIn', true)
          
        }else {
          store.commit('setIsLoggedIn', false)
        }
      })
    })

  }
}
```

I think that my problem can be somehow connected with the fact that before vuex is updated I want to redirect to another route and consequently it takes default values. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common pattern is to have a route that handles user login and this route is public. From this route you could redirect to another routes after the login, and any protected route redirects to the login when there is no logged user.

The logic goes:
Unauthorized user lands in the protected route *A*, before entering, the router redirects to *login*, after the successfull authorization the login redirects to A again.

How does login knows to which route redirects after login??  You can send the name of the redirected route as a route param or query, or you can store the expected route in the store and login redirects to whatever finds in the params, query or store.